# How can you set the search path for JavaToRascal from Java

Tags: java, rascal

We tried to import a test rascal module and a module from the standard library using JavaToRascal.

The test module is stored in `C:\Users\Klemens\workspace\RascalInterop\src\MyTest.rsc` and contains:

```
module MyTest
```

Te java code containing the JavaToRascal invocation is as follows:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.rascalmpl.interpreter.JavaToRascal;
import org.rascalmpl.interpreter.load.IRascalSearchPathContributor;
import org.rascalmpl.interpreter.load.StandardLibraryContributor;
import org.rascalmpl.interpreter.load.URIContributor;
import org.rascalmpl.uri.URIUtil;

public class RascalInterop {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException {
        JavaToRascal j2r = new JavaToRascal(new PrintWriter(System.out), new PrintWriter(System.err));          

        IRascalSearchPathContributor modulePath = new URIContributor(URIUtil.createFileLocation("C:\\Users\\Klemens\\workspace\\RascalInterop\\src\\MyTest.rsc"));        
        j2r.getEvaluator().addRascalSearchPathContributor(modulePath);

        try {
            j2r.eval("import MyTest;").toString(); // Could not import module MyTest: can not find in search path
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            j2r.getEvaluator().addRascalSearchPathContributor(StandardLibraryContributor.getInstance());
            j2r.eval("import IO;").toString(); // null pointer exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getClass());
        }

    }
}
```

The print in the first try block that tries to import our `MyTest.rsc` module results in:

```
Could not import module MyTest: can not find in search path
?[Advice](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Errors/Static/ModuleImport/ModuleImport.html)
```

The second import attempting to import the `IO` module from the standard library results in:

```
class java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any ideas how to use properly set the search path from a Java program?
We tried to use `j2r.getEvaluator().addRascalSearchPathContributor` in various ways but did not succeed in loading a `MyTest.rsc` module from the given directory.

Answer (score 1):

Despite that these API will change in the near future (due to the compilation process and related changes), here's an answer. Two answers actually, one for Rascal files and one for Java code that it needs

For Rascal:

```
 j2r.getEvaluator().addRascalSearchPathContributor
```

What you used is the correct way of doing things. So if it did not work, please provide more code so we can diagnose what goes wrong. So where is your module? Is it in a jar file or a binary folder? If its in a jar, you need some additional wiring I'm glad to explain.

The Rascal search path is distinguished from the Classpath for Java classes which are used by Rascal. So you have different API for that. We use classloaders to find Java files (such that it also works for situations like OSGI bundles in Eclipse):

```
Evaluator x = ctx.getEvaluator();
x.addClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
```

This will make sure that the class loader used to load the current class is also used to load the class linked mentioned in the Rascal file. Of course you can also provide other class loaders. Note that if the libraries you depend on are loaded via OSGI, make sure you get a classloader from a class that is in a bundle that has access to these classes. The simple case is when everything is in the same jar file, then any classloader will do.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the example. The problem consists of two parts:
1. trying to load a self-made module. 2. Trying to load a module from the standard library. I have extended the example to show the concrete problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the path to refer to the `src` directory instead of the source file:

`new URIContributor(URIUtil.createFileLocation("C:\\Users\\Klemens\\workspace\\RascalInterop\\src"));`

Also: probably you should use forward slashes without C:\, so `/Users/.../src`

AFAIK The null pointer exception is expected, evaluating `import` returns null, and you try to call `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the directory and forward slashes, the ModuleImport warning is gone. However the null pointer exception happens on the .eval and not on the .toString call. So the following results in a null pointer exception:

`IRascalSearchPathContributor modulePath = new URIContributor(URIUtil.createFileLocation("C:/Users/Klemens/workspace/RascalInterop/src"));

j2r.getEvaluator().addRascalSearchPathContributor(modulePath);

System.out.println("Eval: import MyTest;");

j2r.eval("import MyTest;");`

Comment: Can  you add a stacktrace? Btw, this is different code from earlier (not stdlib module).